Prove four points are concyclic
Consider triangle $ABC$ and a point $P$ on side $BC$. Let $I$, $I_1$, $I_2$ be the incenters of triangles $ABC$, $ABP$, $APC$ respectively. If the incircles of triangles  $ABC$, $ABP$ and $APC$ are tangent to $BC$ at $D$, $E$ and $F$ respectively, prove that points $I_1$, $P$, $D$, $I_2$ are concyclic.
I tried to solve an orther problem with this lemma and get stuck. Thank you for helping me.

Why do you define $E$ and $F$ ? You don't use them...

oh this is a part of a problem, so $E$ and $F$ use after that.

I wonder where my comments have gone?

As @sirous points out, $I_1PI_2$ is a right angle, so we just need to show that $I_1DI_2$ is also.
Consider $BD-BE-PF$. By the formulae for the distances from each vertex to the neighbouring contact points of the incircle in terms of the side lengths, this equals $$\tfrac{1}{2}(BC+BA-AC)-\tfrac{1}{2}(BP+BA-AP)-\tfrac{1}{2}(PA+PC-AC) = \tfrac{1}{2}(BC-BP-PC)=0.$$ Thus $ED=PF$ and so also $PE = DF$.
Then from right-angled triangle $I_1PI_2$, and the results above, $$I_1I_2^2=(I_1E^2+PE^2) + (I_2F^2+PF^2) =(I_1E^2+DF^2) + (I_2F^2+ED^2)=I_1D^2+I_2D^2,$$ which proves the required result.


Triangle ABC and APC have common angle ACB, so their incenters are colinear, i.e they are on the bisector angle ACB. Similarly incenters of triangles ABC and APC are on the bisector of angle ABC. We show that $O_1O_2$ is the diameter of a circle passins point P. The reason is that the interior and exterior bisectors  of angle APC  are perpendicular, the interior one passes through point $I_1$ and the exterior one passe through point $I_2$. It is clear another point like D on arc $I_1PI_2$ is also on the circle with diameter $O_1O_2$.
Can find another reason for D being on the circle?
Hint: $\angle I_1AK=90^o$, why?

The diagram is very messy. You can use code "Incircle(A, B, C)" to draw incircle of ABC. Also you can turn automatic labelling off by going to Settings > Labelling.

@MyMolecules, Thanks for your advise but I could not find the code for incircle, also setting for lables. I have also another problem the language of software is turned into German and I can not bring it back into English. Any suggestion?

@MyMolecules, May be  it is problem with geogebra classic I am using?

I'm not sure. Are you using this website (this is in english) https://www.geogebra.org/classic?lang=en ?
